# Does the French passé composé have an "emphasis on the result of an action"?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé

For what I mean by "emphasis on the result of an action," please consider this pair of questions:

> Have you been to Paris?
>   Were you in Paris?

The first one may be said to have an "emphasis" on your now knowing what Paris is like as a result of your visit, an emphasis not found in the second line.

This [Web page](https://francais.lingolia.com/en/grammar/tenses/le-passe-compose) by lingolia.com states that the French passé composé has such an "emphasis" (the Web page captured below).

[image]

**QUESTION RESTATED**

I ask the question because most explanations of the passé composé do not mention this "emphasis on the result."  For example, none of these:

- https://www.thoughtco.com/passe-compose-french-compound-past-tense-1368891
- https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/passe-compose/
- https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/passe-compose-vs-imparfait/
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/French/Grammar/Tenses/Present_perfect

The only exception I have found is the Web page from Lingolia.com, as above.

My question as restated is then: Should I accept lingolia.com's representation of the French passé composé as having an emphasis on the result of an action?

**AN ASIDE**

I believe the question may also be equivalent to asking whether the passé composé can (usually does, often does etc.) have a [resultative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative) aspect in addition to any [perfective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfective_aspect) it might have; but please never mind this terminology unless it is helpful.

Comment: Lingolia states "in every day language, the *passé composé* is often used instead of the *passé simple*". That's quite an understatement. The *passé simple* is **never** used in conversational French.

Comment: "Have you been to Paris?" might translate to one of *Tu es allé à Paris ?*, *Tu es déjà allé à Paris ?*, *Tu as été à Paris ?*, *Tu as déjà été à Paris ?* (either of these can be prefixed by *Est-ce que*) while "Were you in Paris?" would translate to *Tu étais à Paris ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

French [english]

Le passé composé est l'équivalent du passé simple dans un récit au passé, lorsqu'on évoque des faits qui se sont produits avant le moment où l'on parle :
[The French perfect tense is the equivalent of the past historic in a tale of the past, when one speaks of facts that occurred before the present moment:]

> Hier, il avait beaucoup de travail ; il a terminé ses devoirs à huit
>   heures.

On pourrait dire : [One could say:]

> Hier, il avait beaucoup de travail ; il termina ses devoirs à huit
>   heures.

Le passé simple s'emploie comme cela dans la langue écrite ; fiction, ouvrages historiques, presse - mais pas toujours !- alors que le passé composé s'emploie plutôt dans la langue oral. [The simple past is used in this way in the written language; fiction, historical works, press-but not always!- whereas the past historic is used rather in the oral language.]

Le passé composé n'est plus l'équivalent du passé simple lorsqu'il est employé dans un récit au présent : [The perfect is no longer the equivalent of the past historic when used in a narrative in the present tense:]

> Il est huit heures ; il a terminé son travail et décide d'aller se
>   promener.

On ne peut pas dire : [one cannot say:]

> Il est huit heures : il termina son travail et décide d'aller se promener.

**L'emploi du passé composé permet ici de mettre l'accent sur l'achèvement de l'action et sut les conséquences dans le moment présent.** [The use of the Perfect here makes it possible to emphasize the completion of the action and the consequences felt in the present moment.]

([Référence: Grammaire: Les Guides. Le Robert & Nathan.](https://www.amazon.fr/guides-Robert-Nathan-Grammaire/dp/2091841730/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1531229721&sr=8-1&keywords=Grammaire%3A%20Les%20Guides.%20Le%20Robert%20%26%20Nathan))

Comment: The bit on "Il est huit heures ; il a terminé son travail et décide d'aller se promener" was particularly helpful. Thanks.